# Can't connect to UniFi APs with ChromeOS ChromeBox

Tags: wifi, ubiquiti, unifi, chrome-os

We have recently replaced our aging HP access points with UniFi AP-AC-Pro and AP-Pro access points. They have all been setup and are working well with all client devices, with the exception of a single Acer ChromeBox CXi - attempting to connect to the SSID results in an "Out Of Range" error message. The AP is directly above the ChromeBox and ChromeOS shows around 75% signal strenth. Other devices in the area are fine.

I have tried powerwashing the ChromeBox - even starting it up after the powerwash the same error happens.

I have changed different security options on the SSID and also set up a new, open, SSID which has the same error message. I set up an open and secured hotspot on my phone, which the ChromeBox connected to absolutely fine. I have patched the machine in with a network cable and that also connects fine, but this is not suitable for permernant use.

There are a number of forum threads regarding issues with ChromeOS machines but there are no resolution threads posted. It was suggested to turn UAPSD (Unscheduled Automatic Power Save Delivery) on the WLAN network off, but this was not on in the first place.

The UniFi Controller is running software 5.0.6.3060.
The UniFi APS are all running software 3.7.5.4969.
The ChromeBox is running the latest version of ChromeOS.

Comment: What do the AP logs say when you try and connect?

Comment: @EEAA there are no records in the UniFi AP of the device ever connecting. The Mac address does not show up in the list of "Known Clients - Ever". I've also checked in the server.log stored on the machine running the AP Controller software and the Mac does not appear there either.

Comment: But did you check the log *on* the AP? That is *much* more detailed than the controller log. You can ssh into the AP and then `tail -f /var/log/messages` IIRC.

Comment: @EEAA logs on the APs do not show the mac address even attempting to connect - of the four aps we have the device's mac doesn't appear in any of the logs.